# How to change the Build agent according to JOB_NAME

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline job for implementing the CI-CD

Currently I am specifing the build agent at the global level.
I want to change it accoring to the JOB_NAME
e.g if the  `env.JOB_NAME=="jenkin-pipeline-admin-portal"` it should build on **build_2** else **build_1**

I have tried to implementing it using Jenkinsfile but didnt worked out,

Can I do something at Jenkins job pipeline level to acchive this ??

Below is my Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
            label "build_2" 
         }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Build-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Building Image..........................'
                script {
                    if(env.JOB_NAME=="jenkin-pipeline-admin-portal"){


                     sh 'sudo docker build -t hostname/admin-portal:1 --build-arg PORT=9007 --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=develop .'

                    }else if(env.JOB_NAME=="jenkin-pipeline-admin-portal-master"){
                    }else{
                         echo 'ELSE block.....................................'
                    }

                }


            }
        }
        stage('Tag-Image') {
            steps {
                  sh 'sudo docker tag hostname/admin-portal:1 hostname/jcibts_swm_dev/admin-portal:latest'
            }
        }
        stage('Push-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Pushing Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker push hostname/jcibts_swm_dev/admin-portal:latest'
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Please let me know what changes I need to do

Answer (score 0):

If you’re not restricted to using declarative Pipeline you can use the scripted approach:

```
def commonSteps() {
    // steps which are common to all JOB_NAMEs
}
if(JOB_NAME==‘jenkin-pipeline-admin-portal’) {
    node(‘build_2’) {
        // body 1
        commonSteps()
    }
} else {
    node(‘build_1’) {
        // body 2
        commonSteps()
    }
}
```